# $X= {\mathbb{R}}^n - \{P \}$ is connected if and only if $n \neq 1$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have problems with this exercisa

Let $p \in {\mathbb{R}}^n, n \geq{1}$ . Prove that $X= {\mathbb{R}}^n - \{P \}$ is connected if and only if $n \neq 1$.

My attempt:

If $n=1$, $(-\infty, P)$ and $(P,\infty)$ is a partition of $X$ for open set, so $X$ it is not connected.

For $n>1$  How do I do it on the roads?

Comment: Well, draw the plane and remove a point. Take any two points on this set, and for sure you will find a *path* joining both points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the statement is more generally true: If $X,Y$ are connected spaces and $A\subsetneq X$ and $B\subsetneq Y$ then $(X\times Y)\setminus (A\times B)$ is connected.

Hint: Let $X-A =\bigcup_{\alpha} X_\alpha$ and $Y-B = \bigcup_\beta Y_\beta$ for connected components $\{X_\alpha\}$ and $\{Y_\beta\}$ for $X-A$ and $Y-B$ respectively. Then $(X\times Y)\setminus (A\times B) = \bigg(\bigcup_{\alpha}(X_\alpha\times Y)\bigg)\cup\bigg(\bigcup_\beta(X\times Y_\beta)\bigg)$

Answer (score 1):

Since connectedness is preserved under homeomorphism we may assume $P=0$. If $x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{0\}$ is a general point then we will show we can connect it to the point $e=(1,0...,0)$ with a path lying in $\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{0\}$. This will show us the space is even path connected.

If $x_i\ne 0$ for some $i\geq 2$ then define a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{0\}$ by $\gamma(t)=(1-t)x+te$. It is easy to check that its image is indeed contained in $\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{0\}$.

If $x_i=0$ for all $i\geq 2$ then define $\mu: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{0\}$ by $\mu(t)=(x_1,t,0,...,0)$. Note that $\mu(0)=x$. Let $y=\mu(1)$. The second coordinate of $y$ is nonzero, so by the first case there is a path between $y$ and $e$. Combining it with $\mu$ we get a path from $x$ to $e$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, we say it is path connected if for all $x, y\in X$ there exists a path between thoses two point.
We can easily show that if $X$ is path connected then it is also connected. I'll let you prove it since it is the crux of the exercice. But I can give you a good hint:

By absurd suppose $X$ non connected, that is $X=U\sqcup V$ a disjoint union of open set.
$\gamma:[0,1]\to X$ is your path ($\gamma(0) =x,\;\gamma(1)=y)$.
Then consider the sets $\gamma^{-1}(U), \;\gamma^{-1}(V)\subset [0,1]$. You can then prove that $[0,1]$ is not connected, which conclude our contradiction.

Then $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{P\}$ connected for $n>1$ follows directly.